# How to send post data value in go-wrk command?

Tags: go

In curl, I can send post data by -d flag like below example

```
curl -X POST -d'{"accountID":"1"}' localhost:1234/geInfo
```

How am I supposed to send accountID value in [go-wrk](https://github.com/adjust/go-wrk) command for a post request?

Comment: From the link you posted: -m="GET": the http request method

Comment: I would guess you simply write -m="POST" instead.

Comment: @TehSphinX -m="POST" just specifies the method. How do I send parameters?

Comment: Hmmm... I followed the -m parameter in the code where it finally ends up being given to this function: req, _ := http.NewRequest(meth, url_, nil) -- meth in there is the -m parameter. But the third parameter is nil and that is where the body (your params) would have to go.

Comment: @TehSphinX Can you explain me using an example go-wrk command with post params?

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, it is (currently) not supported to pass post parameters.

I figured that from the code of go-wrk by following the -m="POST" parameter which suggests otherwise. (Offering the method "POST" of course does not imply you can also pass parameters)

The parameter is parsed in [main.go](https://github.com/adjust/go-wrk/blob/master/main.go):19:

```
method            = flag.String("m", "GET", "the http request method")
```

then passed on to client in [single_node.go](https://github.com/adjust/go-wrk/blob/master/single_node.go):16:

```
go StartClient(
    toCall,
    *headers,
    *method,
    *disableKeepAlives,
    responseChannel,
    wg,
    *totalCalls,
)
```

where it is received in third place in "meth" variable ([client.go](https://github.com/adjust/go-wrk/blob/master/client.go):14):

```
func StartClient(url_, heads, meth string, dka bool, responseChan chan *Response, waitGroup *sync.WaitGroup, tc int) {
```

and then used here ([client.go](https://github.com/adjust/go-wrk/blob/master/client.go):55):

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest(meth, url_, nil)
sets := strings.Split(heads, "\n")

//Split incoming header string by \n and build header pairs
for i := range sets {
    split := strings.SplitN(sets[i], ":", 2)
    if len(split) == 2 {
        req.Header.Set(split[0], split[1])
    }
}

timer := NewTimer()
for {
    timer.Reset()

    resp, err := tr.RoundTrip(req)

    respObj := &Response{}

    (...)

    responseChan <- respObj
}
```

If post parameters would be passable, they would have to be put somewhere into the Request as you can lookup on the [golang http package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) website:

```
func NewRequest(method, urlStr string, body io.Reader) (*Request, error)
```

*NewRequest returns a new Request given a method, URL, and optional body.*